# How does Apple prevent properties from changing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Take a UITableViewCell's imageView's frame property, attempting to set it perfectly valid (doesn't throw any errors) but has no effect, the imageView will not move.

How does Apple prevent frame's from being modified on standard UIKit components (UIImageView for example)?

I need to achieve the same in one of my projects, but I'd prefer not to subclass just to prevent write access to certain properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override layoutSubviews on whatever view it is in, and set the frame there.

Comment: I don't want to change the frame of a UIImageView in a cell, I want to replicate the way the frame is unchangeable.

Comment: That will make the frame unchangeable. It'll be fixed at whatever you set it to in layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (atomic, readonly) NSJonSkeet *jonSkeet;
```

<strike>readonly cannot be used with retain, you have to remove retain from your property if it's there.</strike>

---

I read your question better this time: Apple simply resets the frame when cell.imageView.image equals nil. This is to prevent whitespace in front of the textLabel and detailTextLabel. You can set its frame, but UITableViewCell simply sets it back.

Comment: Please reread my question. I want to avoid subclassing but I want to prevent the frame being changed of existing UIKit objects, which can't be modified.

Comment: Do you also want to avoid Objective-C categories?

Comment: Surely if I use a category it will affect all UIImageViews? I still want to use UIImageViews as normal elsewhere in my app.

Comment: just to point out that readonly can be used with retain, see how topViewController's property is defined in UINavigationController.h.

Comment: @Jonathan then there are only two options: 1) Subclass it. 2) Simply don't send `-setFrame:` to the UIImageView. You could, hypothetically, change the machine code at runtime, but believe me: it's hard.

Comment: @Tom Irvin but does it make any sense?

Comment: Sure does, I do it in my own projects so that I've got the memory management advantages of properties in the .m, but other class files can't set the property. In the .m file you would have a class continuation that redefines the property as retain.

Comment: This *has* to be the first time I see Jon Skeet's name in (an answer to) an Objective-C question.

Comment: Well there's obviously a 3rd way, as the in the situation in my question.

Comment: @Jonathan aah I understand. But the UITableView's UIImageView is moved automatically to the right position before the UITableViewCell is drawn. You can set it's frame, but it's set back a few methods afterwards automatically by UIKit. Apple does this to prevent whitespace when it's image property is nil. Another example: whenever detailTextLabel.text is nil or empty, textLabel will show up in the center. When it is not empty or nil, it'll show above the detailTextLabel.

Comment: @Radek S:how does UIKit/Apple do this?

Comment: @Jonathan in UIKit, UITableView calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` from it's datasource. You implement this method and in it you create the cell. When this method returns, UITableView checks if the imageView in the returned cell contains an image. According to that it sets the frame of the imageView (0,0,0,0 if no image). Then, if there is no image it also sets the frames of the textLabel and detailTextLabel. You can see that if you set the frame in the datasource method it doesn't make any sense as UITableViewCell sets it back automatically as mentioned in the reason a few lines above.

Comment: But cellforrowatindexpath is only called when the tableview is reloaded. So if I change it later say in didselectrowatindexpath the cellFor... Method won't be called.